# Error in training the neural networks

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train the neural network

```
            Ptr< ANN_MLP >  nn = ANN_MLP::create();
                nn->setActivationFunction(cv::ml::ANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM);
                nn->setTrainMethod(cv::ml::ANN_MLP::BACKPROP);
                nn->setBackpropMomentumScale(0.1);
                nn->setBackpropWeightScale(0.1);
                nn->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, (int)100000, 1e-6));

                //setting the NN layer size
                cv::Mat layers = cv::Mat(3, 1, CV_32SC1);
                layers.row(0) = cv::Scalar(4);
                layers.row(1) = cv::Scalar(10);
                layers.row(2) = cv::Scalar(16);
                //layers.row(3) = cv::Scalar(16);
                nn->setLayerSizes(layers);
                nn->train(train_data, ROW_SAMPLE, response);
                cout << "Hari";
                while (1){}
                waitKey(0);
                return 0;
```

trainData is 105735*4 matrix while response is 105735*16 matrix.

The following error is coming-:
                                            Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA81ECA1C8 in BTP.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000322AA5D820.

The error is:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((layout == ROW_SAMPLE && responses.rows == nsamples) || (layout == COL_SAMPLE && responses.cols == nsamples)) in cv::ml::TrainDataImpl::setData, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\ml\src\data.cpp, line 290

Comment: run in debug and get error message

Comment: Hi Miki ,Added the error

Comment: double check that both `train_data` and `response` have the same number of rows.

Comment: Thanx brother that was the mistake